# Is there a possibility to send an interactive map to a group with Telethon?

Tags: geolocation, telegram, telethon

I am using telethon 1.23.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 and I would like to send an interactive Google Map to a group (as a bot). I have got longitude and latitude available.

I was searching the documentation for terms like "map" or "location" and also tried stuff like SendLocation or send_location methods, but without any success.

The only hints I found where methods to send the client's geolocation to the bot (via button press), but this is not what I am looking for.

Is there any wrapping telethon method for this?

Thanks

Andy

Comment: Yes. It's a raw method called `InputMediaGeoPoint` which you pass to `send_file` or `file` argument in `send_message` or `reply` https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/input_media_geo_point.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint, although I seem to miss the exact syntax here. 

I used (bot being my Client connection):
    from telethon.tl.types import InputMediaGeoPoint
    geoPoint = types.InputMediaGeoPoint(gps_x, gps_y)
    await bot.send_file(channel, geoPoint)

and 
`from telethon.tl.types import InputMediaGeoPoint
geoPoint = types.InputMediaGeoPoint(gps_x, gps_y)
async with bot.action(channel, 'location') as action:
            await bot.send_file(channel, geoPoint)`

and some other small tweaks

Do you maybe have a small snippet as a hint?

Thanks
Andy

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting; was retrying several times, but I didn't find the markup for Codeblocks yet ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of Marcel, I finally found a working solution:

```
from telethon.tl import types, functions
geoPoint = types.InputGeoPoint(gps_x, gps_y)
async with bot.action(channel, 'location') as action:
   await bot.send_file(channel, types.InputMediaGeoPoint(geoPoint))
```

I don't know, if this is the finest solution, but it works for me :-)